# JavaScript simple countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a simple JavaScript countdown which counts to 5 and then stops. I want to show the current value (1,2,3,4,5)

I tried:

```
function countdown() {
    jAlert('test', i);
    i++;
    if (i >= 5) {
        clearInterval(aktiv);
    }
};
var aktiv = setInterval('countdown()', 1000);
var i = 0;
```

But every time I insert that `i` in to `jAlert` it wont work any more. What is wrong there?

Comment: @user1689607 - I think it is some kind of function that outputs the number plus the text "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $i = 0;
var $interval = setInterval(function()
{
    if (++$i === 5)
        clearInterval($interval);

    jAlert('test', $i);
},
1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countdown () {
// try to see if passing a string, rather than a number works.
    jAlert('test', i + '');
    i++;
    if (i >= 5) {
         clearInterval(aktiv);
    }
};
var aktiv = setInterval(countdown, 1000);        
var i=0;
```

**Also open the firebug console and tell us what error you are getting when you put the i in jAlert. Or make a jsFiddle if possible.**

Comment: How would this make a difference?

Comment: @user1689607 Because you're sending "countdown" with parameters: () on your original question. Send just the name of the function instead, like this answer.

Comment: @RobinJonsson: I'm not the OP. Are you saying OP originally defined parameters in the `"countdown()"` string in the question?

Comment: @user1689607 Oops! Sorry, confused by your username. Yes that's what i ment. I haven't gotten any setInterval to work with sending the function with parameters.

Comment: @RobinJonsson: That's alright. I should really change the name. But I'm still confused. OP doesn't have any arguments/parameters. Did the original question change?

Comment: @user1689607 Yeah, that would help alot of users :)
Anyway, no, he didn't actually HAVE any arguments, i just pointed out that sending the function WITH parenthesis dosn't work. Therefor the arguments for "setInterval", should be: countdown, 1000

Comment: @RobinJonsson: As long as the function is global, sending a string works fine. It's not recommended, but it works.

Comment: I absolutely agree that there are not enough details, but it does matter that the function is global. If the function is in a local variable scope, the `setInterval` won't find it because the string is eval'd in the global scope.

Comment: I wonder if [this](http://www.smooka.com/projects/jalert/) is the same jAlert, which would require a call from a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to amend this line:

```
var aktiv = setInterval('countdown()', 1000);
```

To this:

```
var aktiv = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Because when I tried javascript for the first time, this interval thingy wouldn't work if i had quotes and / or parenthesis after the function name.

Comment: How would this make a difference? The question states that everything works until `i` is added to `jAlert`.

Comment: @user1689607 - Wait. It *will* make a difference because `setInterval(countdown, 1000)` will pass down the variables and `setInterval('countdown()', 1000)` will not because this is in the global scope.

Comment: @Derek: No it won't. There are no variables being passed. As long as `countdown` is global, and so is `i`, it'll work the same either way. Doing `setInterval(countdown,1000)` doesn't pass anything to the function,.

Comment: @user1689607 - It will. `eval`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/WVPyw/ `reference`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xqdU8/

Comment: @Derek: Your function isn't global in that fiddle.

Comment: @user1689607 - Isn't everything in `eval` is in global?

Comment: @Derek: `setTimeout` will eval the string in the global scope. Because your `loop` function is in the `onload` handler, the `setTimeout` can't find it. More generally, `eval` adopts the variable scope in which it is invoked, so if you made a call like `eval("loop()")` in the `onload` handler, it would find the `loop` function.

Comment: @user1689607 - Well, after all they will still make a difference.

Comment: @Derek: In certain situations, yes, but according to the question, the interval works until the `i` is added to the `jAlert`. Passing a reference instead of a string wouldn't change that.